# Not able to get request headers in http interceptors python fastapi while sending request using axios

Tags: python, axios, cors, http-headers, fastapi

I am using Fast API server and exposed the api. And from my JS using `axios` i am maing call to this server.

And I am using interceptor to check the `token` in `headers`.

I also have added `CORSMiddleware`

Here is the code

```
origins = ["*", "http://localhost:3002"]

# Creating FastAPI Application
app = FastAPI()


app.include_router(chat_service.router)
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"]
)
```

and the interceptor

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def verifyJWT(request: Request, call_next):
    try:
        token = request.headers['token']
        ...
    except:
        return JSONResponse(content={
            "err": "You are not authorized"
        }, status_code=401)
```

And here is the code from JS using `axios`

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
        "accept": "*/*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json" ,
        "token": TOKEN
    },
    data: my_data,
    success: function (botResponse, status) {
        ...
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         .. .
    }
});
```

I am passing the `token` in  `headers`

but on Fast api server it throws the error as there is no token in the headers

and on the console it shows

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8082/api/process' from origin 'http://localhost:3002' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

and if i make the call from `ThunderClient` it works.

what can be the issue and how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `origins = ["*", "http://localhost:3002"]`. As far as I understand, when you have set `allow_credentials=True` in your Middleware, you cannot use the wildcard (i.e. `"*"`) for `allow_origins`.
Here is an excerpt from the docs.

`allow_credentials` - Indicate that cookies should be supported for cross-origin requests. Defaults to False. Also, `allow_origins` cannot be set to ['*'] for credentials to be allowed, origins must be specified.

Link to docs here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/